# add the one values alphanumberic

Tags: php, alphanumeric

I implemented the functionality get the alphanumberic value and plus one value.

```
$string = "VDLE009567";
$person = $numbers = array();

if(preg_match_all('/([a-z ]+[0-9]+)/i', $string, $mt)) {
 $nrmt = count($mt[0]);
 for($i=0; $i<$nrmt; $i++) {
   if(preg_match('/([a-z ]+)([0-9]+)/i', $mt[0][$i], $mt2)) {
     echo $person[$i] = trim($mt2[1]);
     echo $numbers[$i] = $mt2[2];
 }
 }
}
echo $numbers=$numbers[0]+1;
```

i need to get the values as "VDLE009568" but i got the values as "VDLE9568". Is there is any possible way to get this "VDLE009568"

Comment: Question: what should happen if the input is `VDLE999999`?

Comment: Then it should be like this "VDLF0000001"

Comment: So cycling back to 1? Not zero?

Comment: yes its should be adding one plus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code for result

```
<?php
$string = "VDLE999999";
$person = $numbers = array();

if (preg_match_all('/([a-z ]+[0-9]+)/i', $string, $mt)) {
    $nrmt = count($mt[0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nrmt; $i++) {
        if (preg_match('/([a-z ]+)([0-9]+)/i', $mt[0][$i], $mt2)) {
            $personout   = $person[$i] = trim($mt2[1]);
            $numbers[$i] = $mt2[2];
            if ($numbers[0] == 999999) {
                $last      = substr($personout, -1, 1);
                $personout = substr($personout, 0, -1) . (++$last);
                $numbers[0] = 0;
            }
            echo $personout;
        }
    }
}
echo $numbers = str_pad($numbers[0] + 1, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

For result : VDLF000001 [**Online Test Click Here**](https://eval.in/945944)

Comment: it fails in the condition https://3v4l.org/7MZK2 , it should be VDLF0000001

Comment: +Sanjit Bhardwaj This is not my problem. May be not required alpha increase. This is the answer to the this question

Comment: please check the comments in the question

Comment: Ok no problem I'm on it

Comment: it does not add a extra zero means in the starting the digit is 6 digit but after +1 it again of 6 digit

Comment: Yes but, will increase alphanumeric. Everything is ok! You can go to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

for your required condition i made some changes in the code

```
<?php

$string = "VDLE999999";
$person = $numbers = array();
if(preg_match_all('/([a-z ]+[0-9]+)/i', $string, $mt)) {
  $nrmt = count($mt[0]);
 for($i=0; $i<$nrmt; $i++) {
   if(preg_match('/([a-z ]+)([0-9]+)/i', $mt[0][$i], $mt2)) {
      $person[$i] = trim($mt2[1]);
      $numbers[$i] = $mt2[2];
 }
  }
}
  $num = (string)$numbers[0];
  $word_length = strlen($num);
  $max = 9;
  $max_str = '';
  for($i=0;$i<$word_length;$i++){
      $max_str .=$max; 
  }
  $max_str = (int)$max_str;
  if($num < $max_str){
      echo $numbers=str_pad($num+1, $word_length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }else{
        $numbers=str_pad($num+1,$word_length+1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $new_str = strrev((string)$numbers);
        $new_num = (int)$new_str;
        echo $numbers = str_pad($new_num,$word_length+1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
```